# Is it possible to access data in a struct using pointer math in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Is it possible to use pointer math to move through a struct and assign data to its members? I have a large struct with exclusively uint8_t data and writing the names of all these members of the struct is a lot of work. I was hoping I could just assign a pointer to the first data and then add 8 to the address. Is this possible?

```
/* All pieces of data are the same size */
typdef struct 
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c:
}Mydata;

int main(void){

    /* New struct created */
    Mydata NewData;
    /* Pointer P points to the address of "NewData"*/
    uin8_t *p = &NewData;

    *p = 5;
    p = p + 1; // increment 1 byte to next address where data is stored
    *p = 7;
    p = p + 1;
    *p = 10;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not contemplate doing this - it is not portable - it is not readable - it is likely to introduce bugs - it is not maintainable - it is yuk

Comment: Besides if you have a large number of items of the same type - perhaps an array?

Comment: Then why don't you use an array? Alternatively a union with array, and perhaps some static assertions to make sure no padding is there..

Comment: Also the statement _p = p + 8; // increment 8 bits to next address where data is stored_ is incorrect On a 32 bit system (storage for an int) it will increment 256 bits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer math is done in ***bytes***, not bits.
So where you suggested adding by 8-bits, you should actually be adding 1-byte

Structure layout is not guaranteed to be contiguous.   The compiler may choose to put additional blank spaces in the middle of structures that help with alignment and memory access.  Even though you may not know it, it is possible to have:

```
typdef struct 
{
    uint8_t a;
    char    padding_A[3];
    uint8_t b;
    char    padding_B[3];
    uint8_t c:
}Mydata;
```

This will throw off your assumptions and math.
You can often get around this with compiler-specific attributes such as `#pragma pack` or `__attribute__((__packed__))`

Finally, if you ever used this technique, very few engineers would be comfortable maintaining your code.  If any member of the structure ever has its type changed, if any member is added or removed, then every single element-access after that has to be carefully updated.  The risk of a bug is enormous.

There is a common macro available, called [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) that can calculate the byte offset of members from the start of the structure.  This can avoid many of the problems I outlined, and is occasionally used to write highly specialized code.

If you ***must*** do this, use the `offsetof` macro, but before that, take every possible precaution to avoid needing this technique in the first place.

Comment: I would contend that using compiler specific stuff you are usually doing something wrong

Comment: @EdHeal Not necessarily. It's OK if one knows and accepts the consequences.

Comment: @EugeneSh.- That is why I said "usually".

Comment: FWIW for embedded stuff it’s *very* common to use compiler-specific directives.

Comment: "Pointer math is done in bytes" misleads as a +1 in pointer math increments by the size of the referenced data type - that may differ from 1.  It just happens to be 1 in OP's case with `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is almost always a bad decision, since it leads to faults in portability, and in code readability, it can be done.

Pointer math, in C, is based on the datatype of the pointer. The compiler needs to know the size of each element in your pointer to know how to increment the offset.

Declare your pointer as `uint8_t *p` since your are iterating over `uint8_t`.
Then, just `p++` everytime you want to go to the next member in your struct (since the compiler knows the type of your pointer, it know what "1" unit is equivalent to).

I would recommend studying up on pointer math (and pointers in general since they are a major part of C) and, more importantly, I would advise strongly against using pointer math for practicality reasons.

Edit: mispells

Comment: You neglected to mention padding issues, which will make `p++` not work as expected.

Comment: @abelenky The OP claimed the struct had "exclusively uint8_t data", so padding should not be an issue.